# How to make a new pdfLaTeX font family (package)?

Tags: fonts, pdftex, package-writing

I know how to make a simple `.sty` file and use my custom package inside my document.

However, I also know of some packages like `times` or `inconsolata` which provide many different font families to use inside a document which is usable with pdfLaTeX (i.e. using a different font doesn't require Xe- or LuaLaTeX).

Looking at such packages' content on CTAN, I see the package does not consist of only the `.sty` file, but many different file type: `.pfb`, `.tfm`, `.fd`, `.map`, `.enc`, etc. So these are my questions:

- What are the purposes of those files?
- What is required to make the simplest-possible font-family package for pdfLaTeX?
- Can I do something to make a `.ttf` or `.otf` file become a pdfLaTeX package?
- How to make a custom font package which is based on an available package, e.g. add support to another language for my own use? There are many font families which I like really much, but sadly they don't support my native language, which means I can only use it in English documents.

I looked for similar things here but found nothing. I'm sorry in advance if this is a duplicate of some questions.

Comment: your question isn't very clear, an opentype font may have thousands of characters, a font for pdftex can have at most 256, so if you are happy to lose most of the characters in the original font then it is "simply" a matter of converting the font format, but if you need more characters then you have to make multiple fonts in custom encodings and invent macros that keep track of which font has which character, this is done eg for the cjk package, but it is a lot of work to convert each font and these days so much easier to use xetex or luatex directly which can use the original OTF font.

Comment: Read the fontinstallation guide: https://ctan.org/pkg/fontinstallationguide

Comment: @DavidCarlisle My colleagues are (somehow) unhappy with XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX. Btw I see that there are many fonts which are available in my language, but still provide sufficient characters (for my use). I just want to have that set of characters to all of my font. How to do that?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Oh, it is a long document. I will read it now. Thanks!